# Как изменить стиль родительского элемента JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть конструкция:

```
<div style="">
 <button onclick="delDiv()">Удалить</button>
</div>

<div style="">
 <button onclick="delDiv()">Удалить</button>
</div>

<div style="">
 <button onclick="delDiv()">Удалить</button>
</div>
```

Как можно при нажатии кнопки присвоить только своему родительскому элементу div стиль display:none ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function delDiv(elem) {    
    elem.parentElement.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div style="">
 <button onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить1</button>
</div>

<div style="">
 <button onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить2</button>
</div>

<div style="">
 <button onclick="delDiv(this)">Удалить3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Прикольно :) А я всегда `parentNode` использовал